# How to store numbers from a file into an array

Tags: java, arrays, file

I cannot figure out what is wrong with this.
I have to read in a file (the file has numbers) and store the numbers into an array.

Here is the file:

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31878359/courses/15/scores1.txt

I understand the first number is a zero and I cannot change the numbers or the order of the numbers in the file.

**File**
0
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Check {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
           throws FileNotFoundException {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("scores1.txt"));
         process(input);
    }

    public static void process(Scanner input) {
        int[] numbers = new int [input.nextInt()];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        System.out.print("numbers: "+Arrays.toString(numbers));   
   }
}
```

This is the output:

numbers: []

I'm assuming it's a problem with declaring the array.

Comment: Is first value of file, is the size of array? Show your file content.

Comment: input file content please

Comment: Please share the file also.

Comment: so the first number is 0 and you have an array of 0 size

Comment: Change the "0" in the first line of the input file to "9" and it'll work...

Comment: Your file should contain first number as a size of the array.

`int[] numbers = new int [input.nextInt()];` as you are specifying the size of the array here.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that, your first value of file is `0`. So array size is `0`. Change your first value so that, you can get rest of values into array.

Comment: Only changing first value will not solve the overall problem. If first value is made 1, then size of array will be 1. And hence only 1 value will be read from file and inserted into the array.

Answer (score 2):

The first value in the file is 0.

```
int[] numbers = new int [input.nextInt()]; // this input.nextInt() gets the first line
```

You're making an array of size 0

Since there are 10 numbers in the file. initialize with size 10;

```
int[] numbers = new int [10];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void process(Scanner input) {
        List<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while(input.hasNext()) {
            number.add(input.nextInt());//i hope all ints are there in the file
        }
        int[] numbers = number.toArray(new int[number.size])
        //then do sort and all   
   }
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be use `ArrayList`

```
public static void process(Scanner input) {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    while(input.hasNextInt()){
        list.add(input.nextInt());
    }
    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.print("numbers: " + list);   
}
```